# Only tty4 works in Ubuntu and that too remains busy reporting something

Tags: 16.04, gnome, login, tty

I am not able to switch on to other `tty's` except `tty4`. When I switch over to `tty4`, it's always busy reporting somthing like `i2c_hid i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report`.

Reason that I need to switch over to `tty4` - Earlier `tty4` worked properly and since no other tty worked, I had only this option.
 Very often I couldn't log on back(after logging out) to my laptop as login panel wouldn't respond. So, I would just go to tty4, and do nothing, and then switch again to tty7 and login panel started working.

Now, that `tty4` has gone awry, I am afraid I might not be able to login again if login panel becomes irresponsible, might lose unsaved data.

Any sugestions how to bring back `tty4` to work and other `tty's` as well.

Comment: In 16.04, the ttys should be started "on demand" by the getty@.service - do you see any error messages in the journal (ex. `journalctl -xu getty@tty?.service`)?

Comment: @steeldriver: No error messages, Sir. It says `-- No entries --`